# Making a full page div with a navbar in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS and I would like to achieve a layout which includes:

- A sticky navbar
- A full-page section with centered content
- Other sections with variable height
- A footer

Here's a quick representation:

```
+--------------------------+    -+
|  Navbar (sticky)         |     |
|--------------------------|     |
|                          |     |
|                          |     | --> this has viewport height
|    centered content      |     | 
|                          |     |
|                          |     |
|--------------------------|    -+
|                          |
| Section 1                |
|                          |
+--------------------------+              
| Section 2                |
+--------------------------+
| Footer                   |
+--------------------------+
```

I would like the centered content section to take up all the remaining space of the viewport after the navbar, but applying the *h-screen* class causes it to be as height as the viewport causing an overflow. Here's some reproducible code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="h-20 text-5xl sticky top-0 text-center bg-slate-300/50">
      Menu
  </div>
  <div class="h-screen mx-auto bg-indigo-300 flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-5xl">
      content
  </div>
  <div class="h-80 mx-auto bg-green-300 flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-5xl">
      content
  </div>
  <div class="h-20 mx-auto bg-black text-white flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-5xl">
      footer 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me to find a way to make the "centered content" section take up all the remaining space while letting the other, following, sections have an arbitrary height.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 solutions for your layout.

You can add negative margin bottom to sticky navbar `-mb-20`

```html
<div class="h-20 text-5xl sticky top-0 text-center bg-slate-300/50 -mb-20">
  Menu
</div>
```

or you can change you navbar position to `fixed`

```html
<div class="h-20 text-5xl fixed top-0 inset-x-0 text-center bg-slate-300/50">
  Menu
```

Hope this helps.